# Sagemaker endpoint Invocation fails from external application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I followed the steps below:

- Deployed a AWS LLAMA2 foundational model using sagemaker.
- Added Sagemaker full access policy to my IAM user
- Ran **aws configure** for the user above from my local terminal
- Tried to invoke the sagemaker endpoint from my python app and i get the exception as below:

  Error raised by inference endpoint: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: User: arn:aws:iam::***** is not authorized to perform: sagemaker:InvokeEndpoint on resource: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:****/jumpstart-dft-meta-textgeneration-llama-2-7b-f with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy

My IAM user is an admin user.

Could someone please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I created a new user and was able to access the endpoint